# Unable to authenticate on Samba AD DC server

Tags: samba, active-directory, kerberos

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ that I use as a home server.

I have installed and setup Samba AD DC from the Raspbian pacakges (4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u4).

I have configured SSSD on the AD DC server to authenticate the local users.

My setup used to work fine, but, since the beginning of december, I started have all kinds of authentication problems.  Almost all my problems are now resolved, except that I can't authenticate on the local server using AD accounts.

I can authenticate on another Raspberry Pi on my networked that is joined as a domain member and configured with SSSD.

I searched the web for solutions, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the contents of the relevant config files:

*/etc/hostname*

```
pitaya
```

*/etc/resolv.conf*

```
search gggm.int
nameserver 192.168.2.26
```

*/etc/krb5.conf*

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = GGGM.INT
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true

[domain_realm]
    .gggm.int = GGGM.INT
```

*/etc/samba/smb.conf*

```
[global]
    netbios name = PITAYA
    realm = GGGM.INT
    workgroup = GGGM
    server role = active directory domain controller
    dns forwarder = 192.168.2.1
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
    log level = 2
    server string = Pitaya
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    template homedir = /home/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash
    username map = /etc/samba/user.map
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab

    tls enabled = yes
    tls keyfile = /var/lib/samba/private/tls/sambaKey.pem
    tls certfile = /var/lib/samba/private/tls/sambaCert.pem
    tls cafile = /var/lib/samba/private/tls/crt.ca-chain.pem

<Share configuration skipped...>
```

*/etc/sssd/sssd.conf*

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam, sudo, ssh
config_file_version = 2
domains = GGGM.INT
full_name_format = %1$s

[domain/GGGM.INT]
ad_domain = gggm.int
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
sudo_provider = ad
use_fully_qualified_names = false
ldap_id_mapping = false
ldap_referrals = false
override_homedir = /home/%u
enumerate = true
ldap_sudo_search_base = OU=sudoers,OU=gggm.int,DC=gggm,DC=int
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
dyndns_update = false
```

*Output of uname -a*

```
Linux pitaya 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

DNS resolution works fine

```
root@pitaya ~ # host pitaya
pitaya.gggm.int has address 192.168.2.26
root@pitaya ~ # host 192.168.2.26
26.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer pitaya.gggm.int.
root@pitaya ~ # host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.gggm.int
_ldap._tcp.gggm.int has SRV record 0 100 389 pitaya.gggm.int.
root@pitaya ~ # host -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.gggm.int
_kerberos._tcp.gggm.int has SRV record 0 100 88 pitaya.gggm.int.
root@pitaya ~ #
```

I can authenticate using Kerberos as a domain user:

```
root@pitaya ~ # kinit ghigad
Password for ghigad@GGGM.INT:
root@pitaya ~ # klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: ghigad@GGGM.INT

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
03/01/19 12:38:35  03/01/19 22:38:35  krbtgt/GGGM.INT@GGGM.INT
        renew until 04/01/19 12:38:32
root@pitaya ~ #
```

I can list the shares on the local server:

```
root@pitaya ~ # smbclient -k -L pitaya
Domain=[GGGM] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        netlogon        Disk
        sysvol          Disk
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Pitaya)
Domain=[GGGM] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
root@pitaya ~ #
```

I can login using the machine principal.

```
root@pitaya ~ # kdestroy
root@pitaya ~ # kinit -k PITAYA$
root@pitaya ~ # klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: PITAYA$@GGGM.INT

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
03/01/19 12:43:17  03/01/19 22:43:17  krbtgt/GGGM.INT@GGGM.INT
        renew until 04/01/19 12:43:17
root@pitaya ~ #
```

I can also list the shares of the server using `smbclient -k -L pitaya` using this ticket (same output as above).

Also, `wbinfo -u` and `getent passwd` lists the users of the domain.  Likewise, `wbinfo -g` and `getent group` lists the groups of the domain.

Output of `wbinfo -P`

```
checking the NETLOGON for domain[GGGM] dc connection to "pitaya.gggm.int" succeeded
```

I tried to check my domain's DB, and I didn't get any error...

```
root@pitaya ~ # samba-tool dbcheck
Processing section "[netlogon]"
Processing section "[sysvol]"
pm_process() returned Yes
schema_fsmo_init: we are master[yes] updates allowed[no]
schema_fsmo_init: we are master[yes] updates allowed[no]
Checking 400 objects
Checked 400 objects (0 errors)
```

Here is the contents of krb5.keytab.

```
root@pitaya ~ # klist -kte
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:18 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 31/12/18 12:16:19 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
```

However, if I try to authenticate to the domain, plaintext authentication succeeds, but the challenge/response fails.

```
root@pitaya ~ # wbinfo -a ghigad
Enter ghigad's password:
plaintext password authentication succeeded
Enter ghigad's password:
challenge/response password authentication failed
wbcAuthenticateUserEx(GGGM\ghigad): error code was NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD (0xc000006a)
error message was: Wrong Password
Could not authenticate user ghigad with challenge/response
root@pitaya ~ #
```

I tried to reset my user's password (`samba-tool user setpassword ghigad`), but it didn't change anything.

I can't login to my server using SSH and a domain account (on my other server I can...).

Another strange behavior, `kinit -k` fails:

```
root@pitaya ~ # kinit -k
kinit: Preauthentication failed while getting initial credentials
root@pitaya ~ #
```

Digging through the log files, I found this...

```
[2019/01/03 12:51:23.391820,  3] ../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed to decrypt PA-DATA -- host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (enctype aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) error Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type hmac-sha1-96-aes256, key type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2019/01/03 12:51:23.392318,  5] ../source4/dsdb/common/util.c:5252(dsdb_update_bad_pwd_count)
  Not updating badPwdCount on CN=PITAYA,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=gggm,DC=int after wrong password
[2019/01/03 12:51:23.392435,  3] ../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed to decrypt PA-DATA -- host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
```

Also, note that my Windows computers all work fine.  Users can log in and use shared drives.  I can also use RSAT tools (GPO, DNS, Users, Printers, etc.).

I feel my problems come from Kerberos authentication at the service level, but I'm stuck...  I can't figure out how to solve this...

Can anyone help?

If you guys need anymore log, I can add extracts as well...

**Edit**

I kept searching for a solution did an experiment.

I setup another Linux machine as a PDC (`samba-tool domain join gggm.int DC  --dns-backend=SAMBA_INTERNAL --option='idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes'`).  Everything went well, except, that after I joined the domain, the machine started to behave a little like the first one...

`getent passwd` returned the list of users, `getent group` returned the list of groups, but `login ghigad` always failed.

I finally found that enabling the `pac`service in SSSD resolved the problem...

*sssd.conf*

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam, sudo, ssh, pac, ifp
```

So I went on my other problematic server and enabled the `pac` service in SSSD and crossed fingers, hoping that the problem was solved.

Unfortunately, it's not that easy...  I still have strange authentication problems...

I flushed the SSSD cache (`sssctl cache-remove`) and `getent passwd` can no longer list my domain users, and my domain turned offline in SSSD.

```
root@pitaya /usr/sbin # sssctl domain-status gggm.int
Online status: Offline

Active servers:
AD Global Catalog: not connected
AD Domain Controller: pitaya.gggm.int

Discovered AD Global Catalog servers:
None so far.

Discovered AD Domain Controller servers:
- pitaya.gggm.int
```

I tried to regenerate my machine's Keytab, in case it helped.

```
root@pitaya ~ # rm /etc/krb5.keytab
root@pitaya ~ # net ads keytab create -P
kerberos_kinit_password GGGM@GGGM.INT failed: Client not found in Kerberos database
kerberos_kinit_password GGGM@GGGM.INT failed: Client not found in Kerberos database
kerberos_kinit_password GGGM@GGGM.INT failed: Client not found in Kerberos database
kerberos_kinit_password GGGM@GGGM.INT failed: Client not found in Kerberos database
root@pitaya ~ # net ads keytab create -U ghigad
Enter ghigad's password:
kerberos_kinit_password GGGM@GGGM.INT failed: Client not found in Kerberos database
kerberos_kinit_password GGGM@GGGM.INT failed: Client not found in Kerberos database
```

The only way I could recreate the Keytab was by first authenticating with Kerberos.

```
root@pitaya ~ # kinit ghigad
Password for ghigad@GGGM.INT:
root@pitaya ~ # net ads keytab create -k
root@pitaya ~ # klist -ke
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 e3514235-4b06-11d1-ab04-00c04fc2dcd2/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 restrictedkrbhost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
```

I then restarted SSSD and checked the status.  Still offline.

I tried to export the Keytab using samba-tool.

```
root@pitaya ~ # rm /etc/krb5.keytab
root@pitaya ~ # samba-tool domain exportkeytab /etc/krb5.keytab --principal=PITAYA$
Export one principal to /etc/krb5.keytab
root@pitaya ~ # klist -ke
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (arcfour-hmac)
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-md5)
   3 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT (des-cbc-crc)
root@pitaya ~ # service sssd restart
root@pitaya ~ # sssctl domain-status gggm.int
Online status: Online

Active servers:
AD Global Catalog: pitaya.gggm.int
AD Domain Controller: pitaya.gggm.int

Discovered AD Global Catalog servers:
- pitaya.gggm.int

Discovered AD Domain Controller servers:
- pitaya.gggm.int
```

After that, `getent passwd` listed my domain users, but the rest of my Keytab is screwed up.

`kinit -k` still doesn't work because the `host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT` is not in the Keytab, but `kinit -k PITAYA$` works properly.

After that, `smbclient -kL pitaya` works.

I really need to have all the SPNs in my Keytab, but `net ads keytab create` doesn't generate a valid one.

How could I generate a valid Keytab?

I will keep trying to make it work and post my progress here...  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve my problem...

Enabling the pac service in SSSD definitely helped.

*sssd.conf*

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam, sudo, ssh, pac, ifp
```

Also, regenerating the secret keys of the machine finished solving the remaining problems.  The challenge here is that the problematic machine is the AD DC for the domain.  So I could not just rejoin the domain.

The following command regenerated the secret keys of the machine and generated a new Keytab.

```
adcli update --verbose  --computer-password-lifetime=0 --domain=gggm.int
```

Then, checking the keytab:

```
root@pitaya ~ # klist -k
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT
4 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT
4 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT
4 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT
4 PITAYA$@GGGM.INT
4 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 host/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 ldap/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 gc/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 gc/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 RestrictedKrbHost/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
4 krbtgt/PITAYA@GGGM.INT
```

You can see that my Keytab now contains KVNO 4 for all the SPNs of my machine.  So, the following commands now work!

```
root@pitaya ~ # kinit -k
root@pitaya ~ # klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_500_ChLPIV
Default principal: host/pitaya.gggm.int@GGGM.INT
Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
24/01/19 21:18:54  25/01/19 07:18:54  krbtgt/GGGM.INT@GGGM.INT
renew until 25/01/19 21:18:54
root@pitaya ~ # kinit -k PITAYA$
root@pitaya ~ # klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_500_ChLPIV
Default principal: PITAYA$@GGGM.INT
Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
24/01/19 21:19:00  25/01/19 07:19:00  krbtgt/GGGM.INT@GGGM.INT
renew until 25/01/19 21:19:00
root@pitaya ~ # smbclient -kL pitaya
Domain=[GGGM] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
netlogon        Disk
sysvol          Disk
home            Disk
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Pitaya)
Domain=[GGGM] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]
Server               Comment
---------            -------
Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
```

Now, authentication works (`login ghigad` works, dovecot authentication works, etc.) and I can login to the SSH service using GSSAPI.